# no ocijdbc9 in java.library.path

Tags: java, oracle, linker, linker-errors

When I try to run Java application, I receive the following error:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc9 in java.library.path`

I don't have a file `ocijdbc9.*` on my PC, but I have `ocijdbc10.dll` in `%ORACLE_HOME%\bin`.

`%ORACLE_HOME%` is correctly specified, so I think the problem is that the application is searching for the wrong version (9 instead of 10).

Both Oracle and Java Builder are freshly installed, so the problem may be in project preferences? Do you have any ideas on how to search for the place where the wrong version is specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a file from your java CLASSPATH.

You need to add the OCI jar to your classpath.

For my oracle 10.0.2 install on windows it's located in

```
%ORACLE_HOME%\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar
```

If your application requires ocijdbc9 then you'll have to download it from somewhere and add it to the CLASSPATH.  I don't know where to download it from, try the oracle site

Comment: Adding of 'ojdbc14.jar' to classpath solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Download it from "somewhere" means download the Instant Client from the Oracle site. Just download the version corresponding to the required ocijdbc. It will contain the .dll files needed; which you need to copy to either system32 or java path. https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html

Answer (score 2):

an additional tip:
if you're using oci jdbc urls; it is always better to use the jar library of your oracle client version.

please check this address for these libraries: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/index.html

for example if your client is Oracle 10.2.0.4, then you'd better use this client's `ojdbc14.jar` for java >= 1.4 and `classes12.jar` for java <= 1.3

note that until Oracle 11, jdbc libraries have the same names in every version such as `ojdbc14.jar` and `classes12.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `-Djava.library.path=YOUR_ORACLE_HOME\bin` to the JRE as a runtime parameter

So....

```
java [other java switches + runtime parameters] -Djava.library.path=YOUR_ORACLE_HOME\bin run-classname
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it is because you have not yet installed Oracle Client.
After installing it, maybe it is ok

Comment: Answer should be concrete not based on assumptions.