# Oracle JDBC connection: no ocijdbc9 in java.library.path

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am getting the below error while trying to connect to oracle database,
When I searched in the web, the advise is to add the required jar on the classpath, which I already did. I even tried creating a run configuration , added the jar on classpath, still getting the same error.

Please help,

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc9 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at oracle.jdbc.oci8.OCIDBAccess.logon(OCIDBAccess.java:262)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:346)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:468)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:314)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at com.example.DAO1.main(DAO1.java:13)
```

Code:

```
package com.example;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

class DAO1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, IOException {
        // Load the driver
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

        // Connect to the database
        // You can put a database name after the @ sign in the connection URL.
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:oci8:@mydevdb:1521:mysandbox", "uname", "pwd");

        System.out.println(conn);

        // Close the connection
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

I added ojdbc14.jar

Comment: just noticed that after I changed the connection string to 'jdbc:oracle:thin', the error is gone! though not clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the JDBC thin driver, which is 100% Java, not the OCI driver.  That requires a DLL, which the JVM is telling you isn't in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Change the URL to

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydevdb:1521:mysandbox", "uname", "pwd");
```

I don't like the driver JARs you have, either.  I would recommend getting ojdbc6.jar at a minimum.  The ojdbc14.jar is JDK 1.4 vintage - way out of date.

Comment: I changed to jdbc:oracle:thin and checked and the error was gone, though didnt knew the reason +1, thanks for the reason. Regarding the jar version, I picked it up from this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919921/no-ocijdbc9-in-java-library-path . Will update to ojdbc6.jar , I am using jdk1.6 . I could accept as answer soon

Comment: Hi @duffymo - Can you help me on throwing some pointers at this SO question i just posted, when you get a chance - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190219/java-resultset-is-empty-while-calling-stored-procedure-with-ref-cursor-as-out

Answer (score 1):

Never call `DriverManager.registerDriver()` method manually. The JDBC spec requires a driver to register itself when the class is loaded, and the class is loaded via `Class.forName()`. In `JDBC 4` the drivers are able to be loaded automatically just by being on the class path.

Comment: That's how it is in the example from docs.oracle.com:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/java.816/a81354/samapp2.htm

Comment: but sometimes you may end up registering your driver class twice

Comment: I agree that it's not necessary, but it was correct for the earlier JDBC idiom.  Earlier examples will all do it that way.  Doing it twice is not a deal breaker - nano-optimization at best.

Comment: ya @duffymo you are correct and now in JDBC 4 the drivers are able to load automatically if they are in the class path that is one great advancement.

Comment: Great?  Minor at best.

Comment: Thanks M.Sharma for bringing that point +1, though things are more clear on @duffymo comments.

Comment: @duffymo calling `registerDriver` has never been necessary for drivers that actually follow the JDBC specification. Using `Class.forName` is the only thing that used to be necessary (assuming the driver was correctly implemented).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel - yes, I know.  It's a new development in Java.  Not important.