# Java: resultset is empty while calling stored procedure with ref cursor as OUT

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, cursor, resultset

I am trying to call a StoredProcedure from Java, but the result returned is always **false**. In reality, it has to return 100's of records. The connection is established good.

I have a **stored procedure**,

```
 PROCEDURE get_records
   (
      grp1     IN a.name%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
     ,grp2 IN a.name%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
     ,grp3        IN a.name%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
     ,grp4          IN a.name%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
     ,grp5               IN a.name%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
     ,flag1     IN a.flag%TYPE DEFAULT 'F'
     ,flag2       IN a.flag%TYPE DEFAULT 'F'
     ,refercursor_out          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
   );
```

**My java Program:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes;

class DAO1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, IOException {
        // Load the driver
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        Connection conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:admin/admin@//host1:1521/abcdev");
        System.out.println(conn);

        // Prepare to call the stored procedure get_group_details.
        CallableStatement cstmt = conn
                .prepareCall("{call mypackage.get_records (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

        cstmt.registerOutParameter(8, OracleTypes.CURSOR); // REF CURSOR

        cstmt.setString(1, "");
        cstmt.setString(2, "");
        cstmt.setString(3, "");
        cstmt.setString(4, "");
        cstmt.setString(5, "");
        cstmt.setString(6, "");
        cstmt.setString(7, "");

        // execute get_records
        //cstmt.execute(); //updated
        cstmt.executeQuery(); //updated

        ResultSet rs0 = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(8);
        System.out.println("rs0 is " + rs0.next());

        /*
         * ResultSet rs = ((OracleCallableStatement) cstmt).getCursor(8);
         * System.out.println("rs is " + rs.next());
         * 
         * while (rs.next()) { System.out.println(".."); }
         */
        // Close the statement
        cstmt.close();
        // Close the connection
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Current ouput:

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection@5afec107
rs0 is false
```

Question - why is it false? I expect 100's of records in the resultset. There are records, and is visible on executing the test script from sql developer.

```
begin
 mypackage.get_records(refercursor_out => :refercursor_out);
end;
// this returns 100's of records
```

**Update: 08/08**

The reason why I was not getting data is not the code issue, when I passed some value to the 6th parameter, it is returning data. Hence closing the thread; Marking @Klas Lindbäck's  answer as the answer for suggesting the right execute method. [though execute(), executeQuery() and executeUpdate() in this case returns data in the resultset]

Comment: You need to study this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html

Comment: I went through taht especially the topic 'Calling Stored Procedures in Java DB and MySQL' . I still don't understand where I went wrong. The only thing I noticed is`cstmt.executeQuery();` instead of execute() . Can you please be more specific

Comment: why aren't you setting any of the input parameters?

Comment: What's get_records doing?

Comment: @Typo Thanks for looking into this, The input parameters values are optional. The procedure body `get_records` fetches a list of groups. If you see, the procedure i mentioned at the end of the post , is returning that 100's of groups/records

Comment: @Typo you were right in throwing the pointers, thank you

Comment: @duffymo There was no issue with the code, except that data was not returned because the query parameter value was not as expected for the Plsql procedure. Nothing to do with the code. Though you helped in many SO posts, this one was not helpful, but it made me to learn some, thanks

Comment: @prash - can't win 'em all.  I don't always have time to help.  You did need to learn how stored procs work in JDBC.  I would submit that there was a problem with the code.

Comment: Agree to learn, but don't understand what you are referring to the problem with the code. Can you point that out? It would help me as well anybody who search and visit this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the right semantics. `execute` has other semantics than `executeQuery`.

> The execute method returns a boolean to indicate the form of the first result. You must call either the method getResultSet or getUpdateCount to retrieve the result; you must call getMoreResults to move to any subsequent result(s).

The easiest solution (smallest code change) for you is to switch to `executeQuery`:

```
    // execute get_records
    cstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,I tried `executeQuery()`, `execute()` and `executeUpdate()`, but none give me the data.

Comment: The reason why I was not getting data is not the code issue, when I passed some value to the 6th parameter, it is returning data. Hence closing the thread; Marking this as answer for suggesting the right execute method. [though execute(), executeQuery() and executeUpdate() in this case returns data in the resultset]