# Empty ResultSet from PL/SQL procedure returning non-empty rows

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm using `JDBC` to get Results from an Oracle Stored procedure which is using `SYS_REFCURSOR`. When I execute the Stored procedure in `sqlPlus` , I get results , but in Java , I'm getting an empty result set.

I found the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190219/java-resultset-is-empty-while-calling-stored-procedure-with-ref-cursor-as-out) below , which seems to be the perfect solution , except that its not working.

From my logs - this is the final String thats constructed:
call `ENT_GET_USERS`(?,?,?,?)

Could anyone suggest why I'm getting an empty resultset through Java?

I'm using `stmt.registerOutParameter(columnName, OracleTypes.CURSOR);`

As suggested by the link above I changed my code to set `""` for String parameter

```
case Types.VARCHAR:
                            if (inputValue != null)
                                stmt.setString(columnName, inputValue);
                            else
                                stmt.setString(columnName, "");
```

My Procedure definition looks like this:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ENT_GET_USERS(  p_id VARCHAR2 ,  p_id_type VARCHAR2,  p_app_id VARCHAR2 , usr_result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
```

**EDIT1**:
I'm calling from sqlplus like this below

```
SQL> variable rc refcursor;

SQL> exec ENT_GET_USERS(NULL , 'APP' , NULL , :rc ) ;
```

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc ; // This returns results

**EDIT2**:
I created a Test Program , and using a shortened version of Procedure with no luck. Code below:

```
             CallableStatement cstmt = conn
                .prepareCall("{call ETTRDV_EMEA.ENT_GET_USERS (?,?,?,?)}");

        cstmt.registerOutParameter("usr_result", OracleTypes.CURSOR); // REF CURSOR

        cstmt.setString("p_id", "-1");
        cstmt.setString("p_id_type", "APP");
        cstmt.setString("p_app_id", "");

      cstmt.execute(); //updated

        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)cstmt.getObject("usr_result");

        while (rs.next()){
            System.out.println("Next");
        }
```

Output:  Next next.. etc - it works!

Procedure below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ENT_GET_USERS(  p_id VARCHAR2 ,  
                                            p_id_type VARCHAR2,  
                                            p_app_id VARCHAR2 , 
                                            usr_result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
BEGIN
OPEN usr_result for SELECT USR.USR_ID , USR.USR_SID, USR.USR_FIRSTNAME , USR.USR_LASTNAME , USR.REFERENCE_ID , USR.USR_CREATED_BY , USR.USR_CREATED_ON , USR.USR_UPDATED_BY , USR.USR_UPDATED_ON
                              FROM ENT_USERS USR ;
END;
```

And executing from SQLPLUS:

```
exec ENT_GET_USERS('-1' , 'APP' , '', :rc ) ;
```

Which gives me the expected result.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT3:**
Updated the working code above.

Comment: You can `setNull()` instead of passing an empty string, to make it more explicit. Without seeing your data, the query in the procedure, or the parameter values actually being bound it's hard to say. But is the data in your SQL\*Plus session committed?

Comment: I was originally using setNull(). That doesn't work either. The data is commited as it was inserted by the same program that I'm using to fetch and sqlplus is a different session which gives me the results.

Comment: What are you seeing - just that it prints "No results"? Is your real code doing the same test? That is what it should do - the execute result should be false.

Comment: Why would it be false? From the docs - "true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if the first result is an update count or there is no result"

Comment: There is no result from a procedure call. One of the out parameters is a result set (cursor), but that isn't the first result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The booleanresult *should* be false; that does not mean the ref cursor is empty. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()):

> The execute method returns a boolean to indicate the form of the first result. You must call either the method getResultSet or getUpdateCount to retrieve the result; you must call getMoreResults to move to any subsequent result(s).
>
> **Returns:**
>   true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if the first result is an update count or there is no result

There is no result from a procedure call. The return value has nothing to do with whether the out parameter, which this call happens to have and which happens to be a cursor, contains anything.

Since you've trying this in SQL*Plus, at this point it's essentially like you've done the `exec`, but you haven't done anything with `:rc`.

You need to get the cursor, something like:

```
ResultSet rset = cstmt.getCursor("usr_result");
```

or as you aren't using an OracleCallableStatement:

```
ResultSet rset = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject("usr_result");
```

andthen iterate over the result set as you would with one created from a query.

---

I've had mixed results with named parameters, particularly when setting them in a different order to that in which they are defined. You may find you need to use `getCursor(4)` or `getObject(4)`.