# no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path

Tags: java, oracle, dll, oracle11g

I am trying to make a connection to oracle through java program using OCI driver.

Following is the configuration.

- Windows 7, 32 bit.
- JDK 1.7
- Oracle client 11g R2.

`ojdbc7.jar` in the class path of my standalone application.
But I am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path
```

I tried connection using thin driver. For thin driver it is Connection Succeeded.
I googled but was not able to figure out the solution.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: please provide your code.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919921/no-ocijdbc9-in-java-library-path

Comment: Why are you using JNI?  Is there something you can't get from JDBC?

Comment: Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci:@hostname:port_no:xe","USERNAME","PASSWORD"))

Comment: @FlyingGuy If I am using JDBC "Thin" then for remote oracle access i want firewall permission which may not required using "OCI" so..

Comment: Sorry, but that last comment did not make a lot of sense to me.  Both JDBC and OCI connect across a socket and would need the same firewall permissions.

Comment: Now I am even more confused! java.sql.Connection() is implemented in Java and the driver required is a jar file also written in Java.  OCI.* is the Oracle Call Interface written in C as either a DLL for windows machine or a .so for *nix.  You can, if you really want to, call oci via JNI.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions and help. I sort out that exception.

Comment: You are missing a navite library, which would be named `ocijdbc12.dll` if you're on Windows.

Answer (score 45):

I had the same issue, it was just the external folder of the my `*.ora` files which was not there any more, I pointed to it again via (menu navigation):

- Tools

  - Preferences

    - Database

      - Advanced

        - tnsnames directory

**It solved it!**

Answer (score 4):

To use the oracle OCI driver you should have the relevant dlls in your java library path.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/instclnt.htm#CHDIHGEF

Make sure to reference the correct release, both in term of 32/64 bit and version number.

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me, because I was using the wrong version of the ojdbc jar, so it was calling for the wrong version of the oci driver

Answer (score 3):

It has been resolved by setting Oracle client

Tools -> Preference -> Database -> Advanced -> Use Oracle client -> (choose path of oracle client)

ex: Instant Client: `file:/C:/Oracle/product/11.2.0/client_3/`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Rename the `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\System` folder
2. Run the Project from Jdeveloper
3. Close the Jdeveloper
4. Rename back the System folder and try running the project and update the mapping in VO

Answer (score 0):

For JDeveloper 12c, if you come across this issue set up an environment variable  referring to ojdbc jar"

```
-J-Djdbc.library=<PATH>\ojdbc6.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation.

The solution turned out to be to enter the connection property and from this level to reconnect.

I will add that the problem appeared after the installation of oracle express during which an error occurred and the installation was not completed

Answer (score 0):

The error message may be misleading - especially when your application is correctly configured (with all jars in place etc.)

Check the `tnsnames.ora` file if it contains the definition for the database you try to connect to. If not, add it and restart the application.

-- EDIT --

If the definition is there but you can't see any TNSes, check if the syntax is fine. One bracket too much and SQL Developer will ignore the whole file silently...