# How to fix "no ocijdbc12 in java.libary.path" on Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I try to access DB server by Oracle SQL Developer then I found following display below.

[image]

**I try to fixed on other posts already but it didn't work.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445610/no-ocijdbc12-in-java-library-path)

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think they different case he make a connection by Java program

Comment: The problem is the same though. Same error and I've looked the answers there none of then are code related they are all "client" configurations, so you probably have to do one of those suggestions.

Comment: @JorgeCampos For now I got this error "oracle/jdbc/driver/GeneratedPhysicalConnection$1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to fix this:

1. don't make a connection request that is trying to pull in the OCI library - in other words, stay with JDBC THIN
2. configure SQL Developer such that your Oracle Client can be loaded for a THICK (OCI) connection

Option 1:
In your connection properties, if you're using TNS, use a Network Alias, NOT a Connect Identifier.

Otherwise, as long as you do not have 'Use OCI' enabled in your advanced connection properties or Advanced Database Preferences, you should have a THIN connection.

Option 2:
Go into the preferences and correctly configure the Oracle Client section of the Advanced Database page.

[image]

[I talk about this in more detail here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/01/oracle-sql-developer-4-and-the-oracle-client/)

Comment: I try second way then found this error  "The native OCI driver could not be loaded. The system propertyjava.library.path contains the entries from the environment variable PATH. Check it to verify that
  the expected native library directory D:\Oracle\app\User\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin is present and precedes any other client installations." Please kindly help me to fix this.

Comment: I try first way then found the same error, I mean try make a connection JDBC THIN.

Comment: For now I got this issue "oracle/jdbc/driver/GeneratedPhysicalConnection$1".

Comment: @BoonrungKasemsak it means your instant client 'install' isn't quite good - you need to make sure that directory is listed FIRST. How did you go about making your connection 'THIN' - did you disable 'use oci' in preferences and define a Basic connection?

Comment: Yes, I uncheck Use OCI/THICK driver. For now I didn't find this error but I found the new error was 17002 please help me to fix this in other my post. I have one question, My friend connect by TNS type but I tested connection it by JDBC THIN first I understand it should be connect success after that I will try to TNS type, this correct or not ?